# Password issue when adding user

Tags: users, useradd

I have run the command

```
sudo useradd testuser
```

Then when I run

```
su testuser
```

it ask for a password, and I have not set a password. So no matter what I type it gives me an authentication failure...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

`useradd` does not ask/set the password. You need to set the password with the `passwd` command (so that the hashed password gets written in `/etc/shadow`):

```
sudo passwd testuser
```

Also, `useradd` is a low level utility, you need to specify options specifically, you might also need to create home directory for the user and set a login shell e.g.:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/testuser -m -s /bin/bash testuser
```

---

If you are on Debian (or any of it's derivatives), look at the `adduser` wrapper.

Comment: The OP wants testuser to not have a password, so this answer does not help